# Using reactivity to add multiple variables

Tags: r, shiny, reactive

I want to add variables one after another using the action button in R shiny.
For example, I want to create an equation like this: Y=X1+X2+X3. However, I have to do this by adding an individual variable one at a time and pressing an action button.

Steps:

1. select dependent variable (Y) which will be the same and will not change.
2. select one independent variable: (X1) and press `calculate`. The UI will show `Y=X1`
3. If I again select a different independent variable (X2) and press `calculate`, UI should show `Y=X1+X2`
4. continue this process if the action button is further clicked.

Assume that only the addition of variables is possible.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)

ui <-  
  dashboardPage(
    dashboardHeader(),
    dashboardSidebar(
    selectInput("dep_var", label = "dependent",  choices = c('Y', 'Z'), selected = 'Y', multiple = F),
    selectInput("ind_var", label = "Independent",  choices = c('X1', 'X2', 'X3', 'X4'), selected = 'X1', multiple = F),
    actionButton("add_equation", "Add equation"),
    actionButton('clear', 'Clear equation')),
    dashboardBody(uiOutput('equation'))
    )

server <-function(input, output) {
  
  x_var <- reactive({
    x = paste0(input$ind_var)
    x
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$add_equation, {
    isolate(x_var())
  })  
  
  observeEvent(input$clear, {
    input$ind_var <- NULL
    input$dep_var <- NULL
  })  
  output$equation <- renderUI({
    paste0(input$dep_var, '=', x_var())
  })
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot modify user input variables `input$ind_var`, and `input$dep_var`.  Instead create `reactiveValues` object and modify it.  Try this

```
server <-function(input, output) {
  y_var <- reactiveValues(eqn=NULL)
  cntr <- reactiveVal(1)
  
  observeEvent(input$add_equation, {
    if (cntr()==1) {
      cntr(2)
      y_var$eqn <- paste0(input$ind_var)
    }else {
      cntr(cntr() + 1)
      y_var$eqn <- paste0(y_var$eqn,' + ', input$ind_var)
    }
  })  
  
  observeEvent(input$clear, {
    cntr(1)
    y_var$eqn <- NULL
  })  
  output$equation <- renderUI({
    paste0(input$dep_var, '=', y_var$eqn)
  })
  
}
```